# Runtime Error with DDD

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, ddd-debugger

Trying out DDD for the first time in conjunction with some C++ code I already have written and compiled on another machine. When I run DD with the code, I get this error:

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what(): User configuration file not found

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6f84428 in __GT_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54 (gdb)
```

Not sure what to think, as I have the code built and running on an RPi. Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: «User configuration file not found» doesn't bring you any thoughts? BTW DDD is dead for almost 9 years now...

Comment: You should include a [mcve] and indicate *how* you compiled it - especially if you cross-compiled on a a different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run DD with the code, I get this error

That is an error from *your* program (which throws exception).

You can find out where that error is coming from using the GDB `where` command.

If your program doesn't throw this exception when you run it outside of DDD, it's likely that your program looks for "configuration file" in its current directory (bad idea (TM)), and that the directory in which you start it is different from the directory in which DDD starts it.

You can use `cd` command inside DDD to change the current directory, and this will likely "fix it" for you (but really you should fix your program so that it uses `$HOME` or some other well defined location for its configuration files).